# How can I create double or thrice power key listener?

Tags: android

I have a question to all of you! Is there any way to detect if power key has been pressed two or three times.

Here is my code to detect power key press:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
       if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
              Log.e("iufehthrhhrhyigy", "dhytfwsthrytfy.");
            wasScreenOn = false;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                  Log.e("iufyigy", "dhytfytfy.");
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
```

Comment: take a static variable as counter and increase counter. and also you have to increase between some time period like 1 sec or less.

Comment: i did that but not working

Comment: Why not? Please show your code.

Comment: I don't see any counter in your code

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: actually it works on single press too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your BroadcastReceiver class like this:

```
public class MyBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private int count = 0;
private long last_click = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - last_click) > 1000) { // I'm counting only number of presses in one second. You can adjust it.
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count++;

        Log.d("Log", "count: " + count);

        if (count == 2) {
            Log.d("Log", "Pressed two times");
        }

        if (count == 3) {
            Log.d("Log", "Pressed three times");
        }

        if (count == 4) {
            Log.d("Log", "Pressed four  times");
        }

       // and so on... byw, you better use switch statement here
        return;
    }

    last_click = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Create object of that reciever and register it like this:

```
    MyBroadCastReciever myBroadCastReciever = new MyBroadCastReciever();
    IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
    screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(myBroadCastReciever, screenStateFilter);
```

And don't forget to unregister it when you are done:

```
    unregisterReceiver(myBroadCastReciever);
```

I tested it myself. It's working in my case. Hope it helps you too!

Comment: thanku  its working , butit does not catch (3 click) in every time